# PrimeReact Datatable cannot use onCellClick while having a checkbox column

Tags: reactjs, datatable, cell, checkboxlist, primereact

Hello I have an issue with PrimeReact were I cannot use `onCellClick={() => console.log("clicked")}` OR `onCellSelect={() => console.log("select")}` while having a checkbox column

```
<Column
          selectionMode="multiple"
          headerStyle={{ width: "3rem" }}
        ></Column>
```

I wanted to know if it is a known issue and if there is a workaround.

Here is a demo on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-demo-forked-6vyf5l?file=/src/App.js

Regards

I tried creating my own checkbox column. however I cant update the state of the checkbox. Since I can't pass a function/state updater.

```
<Column
          selectionMode="multiple"
          onClick= ...
          headerStyle={{ width: "3rem" }}
        ></Column>
```

Answer (score 0):

See my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-demo-forked-9jjmhw?file=/src/App.js

CellSelection is NOT allowed in checkbox mode or radio mode but only on single select mode.  It is due to this code in PrimeReact.

```js
const allowCellSelection = () => {
    return props.cellSelection && !isRadioSelectionModeInColumn && !isCheckboxSelectionModeInColumn;
};
```